# Security Concerns with Login and Register Django HTML Template and Views.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication

Do you have any security concerns with what I've done being implemented in a production web app? Either in the Django HTML Template or my views logic?

I would prefer to have the form in actual html rather than using {{ form }}. Is it ok to allow the user to implement very basic passwords?

views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login
from django.contrib import auth
from memberships.models import UserMembership
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from companies.models import Profile


# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # User has info and wants an account now!

        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'error': 'Email has already been taken'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                auth.login(request, user)
                company = Profile()
                company.businessperson = request.user
                company.first_name = request.POST['firstname']
                company.last_name = request.POST['lastname']
                company.company_name = request.POST['companyname']
                company.phone_number = request.POST['phonenum']
                company.save()
                return redirect('memberships:payment')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'error': 'Passwords must match'})
    # User wants to enter info
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = authenticate(email=request.POST["email"], password=request.POST["password"])
        if user is not None:
            # Our backend authenticated the credentials
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            # Backend did not authenticate the credentials
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {"error": "Incorrect email and or password"})

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
```

forms in login.html and register.html:

```
<!-- login.html -->
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="exampleInputPassword" >
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>

  <!-- register.html -->
  <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="exampleFirstName" >

    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="exampleLastName" >

    <input type="text" name="companyname" id="exampleInputCompany" >

    <input type="tel" name="phonenum" id="exampleInputPhone" placeholder="Phone Number">

    <input type="email" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>

    <input type="password" name="password1" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="password" name="password2" id="exampleRepeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Register Account">
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't see what putting your form in "HTML" has to do with security concerns. Note though that that is not the only alternative to just doing `{{ form }}`, you can output each field individually as shown in the form docs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm aware of {{ forms.email }} being an option. Thanks. How about my views.py any security risks with how that is set? And I implemented AbstractBaseUser to customize to allow email instead of username, are there any security risks with this, if not implemented correctly? Or since from django.contrib.auth import authenticate is still in place, should I not be concerned?

Comment: Well the major potential issue in your code is that you don't use a form at all even in the view, so you don't validate any of the fields. I wouldn't call that a security issue, but it is certainly an issue that can cause your view to 500.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how do I use a form in my view, while maintaining my login.html and register.html unchanged? I though type="email" and making certain fields required in html would be sufficient as a logic check.